# Find difference between 2 dates with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date

I get 2 dates from MySQL something like this:

Start: `2015-11-01 22:56:59` End: `2015-11-03 00:00:00`

Also I get dates from object array; here is what one object looks like:

```
Array[5]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:9"
created_at: "2015-10-23 03:36:11"
expiration_date: "2015-11-03 00:00:00"
id: 1
name: "TEST PROJECT"
```

I need to find how many days left with AngularJS...

Comment: you could use momentjs to get the difference between the dates and then display them in a useful format using a filter

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/2435473

Comment: Not duplicat I need to find diffrence between dates from MySQL and to get diffirence directly  inside  template.

Answer (score 7):

Its simple. Use the function as:

```
$scope.calcDiff = function(firstDate, secondDate){
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds    
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
}
```

Comment: Not simple because I get date from mysql in this format: `2015-11-01 22:56:59` and my dates are inside object array...

Comment: Call as $scope.calcDiff(new Date("2015-10-23 03:36:11"), new Date("2015-11-03 00:00:00"));

Answer (score 7):

Consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for all your javascript date and time manipulations.

With the moment library it is as easy as:

```
moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'days')
```

Comment: Problem with It is my dates are inside array of objects, so I can only find diffrence directly inside template or to set new value inside each object...

Comment: You can use the above in template, just add curlys: {{moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'days')}}

Answer (score 3):

You just need to write a `js` function, that do all calculation instead of you.

```
<label>{{diffDate(date1, date2) }} </label>


  $scope.diffDate = function(date1, date2){
          var dateOut1 = new Date(date1); // it will work if date1 is in ISO format
           var dateOut2 = new Date(date2);

          var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
          var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
          alert(diffDays);
          return dateOut;
    };
```

If your data is not in ISO format, you have to set it explicitly.

```
var dateString = "2015-01-16 22:15:00";
var date = Date.parse(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I get date from mysql in this format: `2015-11-01 22:56:59` and my dates are inside object array...

Comment: You can put into the function an array  as parameter and work with that.

Comment: But how I will set up new value for each object inside array? I updated main post how object look like

Answer (score 0):

You can use amDifference filter. Don't forget to inject $filter

```
let dif = $filter('amDifference')(date1, date2, 'days');
```